# Git rebase wrong commits

Tags: git, rebase

I have pushed one commit (Helm chart) to the wrong branch, then CI has automatically created Helm package and another commit on this branch. Then another user has pushed his commit on the same branch. So the git log says:

```
commit 100d13 (HEAD -> MyNewBranch, origin/release/1.2.3.4, origin/MyNewBranch)
Merge: 4a1ea73 af30075
Author: xyz
Date:   Wed Feb 20 17:22:41 2019 +0000

    Merge pull request #14 from Repo/branch-1

    commit message

commit af30075 (origin/branch-1)
Author: Build Bot
Date:   Wed Feb 20 17:20:45 2019 +0000

    [ci skip] build 94:

commit 67d5135
Author: abc
Date:   Wed Feb 20 17:09:41 2019 +0000

    commit message

commit 4a1ea73
Author: Build Bot
Date:   Tue Feb 19 10:21:28 2019 +0000

    [ci skip] build 88: Added prometheus-0.2.0.tgz to repo.

commit 63fac96
Author: Me
Date:   Tue Feb 19 10:17:40 2019 +0000

    My wrong commit message

commit 26bd737
Merge: 1059c5f 25c082a
Author: xyz
Date:   Thu Feb 14 09:08:25 2019 +0000

    Merge pull request #8 from Repo/branch-2

    commit message
```

So in the commit 100d13 I have created new branch from the origin/release/1.2.3.4 which is the one I have pushed my changes to. What I want is to rebase only 63fac96 and 4a1ea73 to origin/MyNewBranch. How can I do this properly?

edit:

```
                               /--- origin/MyNewBranch ---
--- origin/release/1.2.3.4 ---/
```

I want rebase two commits 63fac96 and 4a1ea73 from release/1.2.3.4 to origin/MyNewBranch and have them only there.

Comment: I can't follow your question just based on a vague description and a screen dump.  Please include branch diagrams if possible.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question as this:

You accidentally merged two commits into release/1.2.3.4 that were intended for another branch. Someone else committed to the same branch after this.

You want those commits removed from the release/1.2.3.4 branch and moved to a new branch where they belong.

---

My assumptions:

- you don't care about preserving the SHA1 of those commits (i.e. I'm proposing cherry-pick).
- you do want to preserve the history on the release branch.
- you don't care about preserving the state on the existing MyNewBranch. Creating a new one in its place is ok for you.

Solution:

#### MyNewBranch

- delete the branch MyNewBranch. You're going to create a new one with the same name:

```
git branch -D MyNewBranch
```

- checkout 26bd737 (the SHA1 before the accident happened):

```
git checkout 26bd737
```

- create the new branch from there:

```
git checkout -b MyNewBranch
```

- cherry pick the two commits in the right order:

```
git cherry-pick 63fac96
git cherry-pick 4a1ea73
```

- push this branch:

```
git push origin MyNewBranch --force
```

This branch is done.

#### release/1.2.3.4

- checkout the release branch:

```
git checkout release/1.2.3.4
```

- revert the two commits that shouldn't be there in the reverse order to what they were committed in:

```
git revert 4a1ea73
git revert 63fac96
```

- push that branch:

```
git push origin release/1.2.3.4
```

That's it. You're finished. Helm presumably will create a new package.

Comment: This is what I have tried before. That gives me: Auto-merging repo/index.yaml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in repo/index.yaml
error: could not apply af30075... [ci skip] build 94:

Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".

Could not apply af30075... [ci skip] build 94:

Comment: If you contact me on LinkedIn and show me exactly what happens when you do each of the above steps I can probably help.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I have eventually removed my commits and pushed them again.